# Windows licensing when migrating to a new harddrive?

Tags: windows-10

I had a notebook, but unfortunately it failed.

I had to replace the hard drive (and also likely the mainboard).

On the notebook Windows10 was preinstalled, with license.

Now, (how) can I reinstall Windows10 with the original license?

Or I shall install a fresh one and buy a new license?

Comment: If it were just the hard drive then Windows would simply reactivate itself as your computer would have a digital licence stored with Microsoft. Changing the motherboard would break that, but depending on the manufacturer it might already have a licence associated with it so again simply reinstalling Windows *might* work. I would simply try to install Windows from a clean download from Microsoft, skip adding the licence and check licence status after connecting to the internet. If it activated itself then you're good to go, if it doesn't then you should be able to buy a licence from the store.

Comment: To piggy-back on @Mokubai's comment, since the PC came with Win10 from the OEM, the BIOS/UEFI firmware has an OEM Windows key saved within it - run Windows Update to activate Windows. LPChip's answer to use a Microsoft account is recommended since the key is then saved to your Microsoft account _(deactivate device licenses directly from there)_. Every OEM PC comes with two product keys, an OEM key saved in the BIOS/UEFI firmware and a second product key with a CoA on the PC's casing by law. [Belarc Advisor](https://www.belarc.com/products/belarc-advisor) lists all license keys installed.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 uses a *digital license* which is associated with the
fingerprint of your hardware, taking in account elements such as
the motherboard, network adapter, disk, and more.

However, Microsoft forgives small differences in hardware.
A new disk is counted only as a small change.

Once Windows 10 is installed (or cloned) into the new disk and it
replaces the old disk, Windows should activate itself automatically
once it contacts the Microsoft license servers.

Comment: "I  had to replace the hard drive (and also likely the mainboard."

Comment: @Moab: I don't understand "likely", but if he did change the motherboard, then the question is if his Windows version is OEM (came with the computer) or Retail (bought with a serial number). In the second case he just inputs the serial to activate, and in the first he will have to contact Microsoft Support and ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

When you have small changes in hardware, it is not a problem, but a harddisk and a motherboard will likely not activate windows.

The easiest way to make sure this works, is first change your local account to a microsoft account (with email address) and at least once reboot and login. Windows will write the license to your microsoft account. If you reinstall windows to a new system and it is not automatically activated, you can activate it using your microsoft account and it should activate then.

Comment: The problem with this is that my old config is not bootable anymore.